# Composing a pdf-file by filling a pdf-form programmatically or by composing a SwiftUI-View and convert it to a pdf?

Tags: forms, pdf, swiftui, adobe, pdfkit

I have a question for the best approach to code an app with the ability to convert a SwiftUI View into a PDF-file.

With my app I want to enable the users to compose a PDF-file with an image, with texts, with links and with some calculated values for later printing by AirPrint and  sending as an email-attachment

What is the right way to go in coding with SwiftUI:
Composing a View, rendering the View and thereafter creating the PDF

or

is it possible to prepare a PDF-form with Adobe DC, then use the app's data for filling it programmatically with the help of the ?framework PDFKit? including images and maybe an empty table as well?

Thx for any helpful hint.
I don‘t wait for any code, please just send some words for my further working in your opinion.
Franz